# What does 出す mean in this sentence?

Tags: words

I found this phrase in a movie:

> 今年　最初のセーターをおととい私は出しました

What does 出す mean?

返事してくれてありがとう。

Comment: ありがとう is for what they've done. "Thank you in advance" is よろしくお願いします.

Comment: without further context, i’m just guessing, but it sounds to me like they’re say “the other day was the first i took out my sweater this year”.

Answer (score 6):

This is about the seasonal change of clothing. 出す, in general, means "to put/take out (from inside)". In this context, the sweater is taken out of storage and moved to the stack of clothes worn daily, in accordance with the transition of the seasons.

So

> Two days ago, I brought my first sweater out of storage this year (because it's getting colder).

（夏服/冬服/ etc.）を出す is a collocation often seen, the antonym being (服) をしまう ("to put clothing away").

Comment: My lack of volabulary forced me to write this awkward text. Let me know if there's anything that can't be parsed. Edits will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The grammar in your response was great! Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Your answer is **very** clear and well written, and there's nothing in it that can't be parsed; however, since you specifically requested edits, I've submitted a few minor ones just to make it a little more idiomatic.